# How to place an image into a tabularx booktabs table without moving the text in the same row, and align it vertically to the center?

Tags: tabularx, includegraphics

I am sorry if this is easy, but I am stuck with this and I was browsing many other answers already which did not help me. I tried using raisebox and it helped me a little bit. But raisebox and valign did not help me either. I will post the current code with the raisebox command since it was looking the best out of all options. I will post my own columntype I got from another post which I used in my document. I can't post the full document because it is too long. I also want to use figures in every row but I am stuck with the first one.

I basically want to have the image both vertically and horizontally centered inside the row, and not to create a blank space above my text in the same row.

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[htbp] \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYXX}
\toprule
Parameter & Unit & Description & Figure \\ 
\toprule
Infill Density & \% & Density of the infill structure. Ranges from zero percent (hollow part) to one hundred percent (solid part)  & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{/graphics/veranschaulichung/infill}} \\ 
\midrule
Infill Structure & - & Geometry of the infill structure & \\ 
\midrule
Shell/Wall Thickness & mm & Thickness of vertical walls & \\ 
\midrule
Layer Height & mm & Controls the distance of the nozzle to the previous layer/build platform & \\ 
\midrule
Nozzle Temperature & °C & Temperature used to melt the material & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Important parameters influencing the mechanical properties of additively manufactured components}
\label{table_addparam}
\end{table}
```

[image: My graphic moves the text and creates a blank space.]

Comment: change `\raisebox{-.5\height}`  `\raisebox{-1.2\height}` or some such

Comment: 0.9 seemed about right... but then i will have to manually adjust the next figures, too, right? Is there not a simple way to automate this?

Comment: you have not provided any example but from your image it appears your Y and X columns align on first baseline so .9 will always leave it just below the top so OK

Comment: I tried it out, i just had misunderstood the raisebox and height command, thank you! I also realized I wanted to center align everything so i used `\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}`. I just do not know how to apply it to only one table yet. But it works for me now.

Comment: you can define \tabularxcolumn in a group eg in the table environment for just that table

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

It redefines `\tabularxcolumn` to make a vertically centered `X` column. It also centers cells horizontally.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}        
    
    \begin{table}[htbp] 
        \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            \toprule
            Parameter & Unit & Description & Figure \\ 
            \toprule
            Infill Density & \% & Density of the infill structure. Ranges from zero percent (hollow part) to one hundred percent (solid part)  & \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\ 
            \midrule
            Infill Structure & - & Geometry of the infill structure & \\ 
            \midrule
            Shell/Wall Thickness & mm & Thickness of vertical walls & \\ 
            \midrule
            Layer Height & mm & Controls the distance of the nozzle to the previous layer/build platform &\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\         
            \midrule
            Nozzle Temperature & °C & Temperature used to melt the material & \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Important parameters influencing the mechanical properties of additively manufactured components}
        \label{table_addparam}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd not use vertical centering. But if you so prefer, use the `\tabularxcolumn` method of the first table.

In either case, I'd just expand the third column and leave the other three at their natural size, to not get oversized blank spaces and reserve the greater part to the long texts.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}        
    
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lcXc@{}}
\toprule
Parameter & Unit & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} & Figure \\ 
\toprule
Infill Density & \% &
  Density of the infill structure. Ranges from zero percent (hollow part) 
  to one hundred percent (solid part)  &
  \includegraphics[width=0.125\columnwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} \\ 
\midrule
Infill Structure & -- & Geometry of the infill structure & \\ 
\midrule
Shell/Wall Thickness & mm & Thickness of vertical walls & \\ 
\midrule
Layer Height & mm &
  Controls the distance of the nozzle to the previous layer/build platform &
  \includegraphics[width=0.125\columnwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b} \\         
\midrule
Nozzle Temperature & °C & Temperature used to melt the material & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Important parameters influencing the mechanical properties of 
  additively manufactured components}
\label{table_addparam}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lcXc@{}}
\toprule
Parameter & Unit & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} & Figure \\ 
\toprule
Infill Density & \% &
  Density of the infill structure. Ranges from zero percent (hollow part) 
  to one hundred percent (solid part)  &
  \includegraphics[width=0.125\columnwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} \\ 
\midrule
Infill Structure & -- & Geometry of the infill structure & \\ 
\midrule
Shell/Wall Thickness & mm & Thickness of vertical walls & \\ 
\midrule
Layer Height & mm &
  Controls the distance of the nozzle to the previous layer/build platform &
  \includegraphics[width=0.125\columnwidth,valign=t]{example-image-b} \\         
\midrule
Nozzle Temperature & °C & Temperature used to melt the material & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Important parameters influencing the mechanical properties of 
  additively manufactured components}
\label{table_addparam2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can still use top aligned columns and a middle aligned image using `\raisebox`, but you need to pre-compute the height and depth of the text it is to be aligned with.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}        
    
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering
\setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}% width of X column
\sbox0{\parbox[t]{\dimen0}{Density of the infill structure. Ranges from zero percent (hollow part) to one hundred percent (solid part)}}% measure

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYXX}
\toprule
Parameter & Unit & Description & Figure \\ 
\toprule
Infill Density & \% & \usebox0 & \hfil\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0-0.5\height}%
  {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}} \\ 
\midrule
Infill Structure & - & Geometry of the infill structure & \\ 
\midrule
Shell/Wall Thickness & mm & Thickness of vertical walls & \\ 
\midrule
Layer Height & mm & Controls the distance of the nozzle to the previous layer/build platform & \\ 
\midrule
Nozzle Temperature & °C & Temperature used to melt the material & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Important parameters influencing the mechanical properties of additively manufactured components}
\label{table_addparam}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```